# Possible to log a route with query parameters before routing in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-routing

I have to reroute within an application in **Angular 2.4** with **typescript**. The rerouting happens by pressing a button. The respective code is as follows:

**`component.html`**

```
<button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" (click)="negotiation()"
                            [disabled]="!negotiationEnable"
                            [hidden]="!hiddenElement">
                        Rerouting Button
</button>
```

**`component.ts`**

```
negotiation(): void {
        // == Console.log this path with parameters here.. ==
        this.router.navigate(['/simple-search-details'],
            { queryParams: {id: this._negotiation_id, catalogueId: this._negotation_catalogue_id} });
    }
```

The problem lies in the fact that the URL where it needs to be rerouted within the app is still under development however it would be nice to know how the link looks with the query Parameters and the URL.

If I do `console.log(this.router.navigate(...))` of the command it does produce an Error.

#### Expected Result

`/simple-search-details?catalogueId=blah-foo-1bar&id=some-text-id`

Comment: Can't you just console.log(`/simple-search-details?catalogueId=${this._negotation_catalogue_id}&id=${this._negotiation_id}`)?

Comment: will that be the same as the `this.router.navigate()`? I was just curious as to whether the `queryParams` within the function call does the same or not

Comment: Do you only want to capture this specific route?

Comment: Yes, however what would you suggest otherwise?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In that Component's `constructor()`, add a listener for navigation events:

```
import { Router, NavigationStart } from '@angular/router';

constructor (private _router: Router) {
  _router.events.subscribe(event => {
    if(navigationEvent instanceof NavigationStart) {
      console.log(navigationEvent.url);
    }
  })
}
```

The `NavigationStart` event uses an interface that presents a route ID and the URL with parameters replaced by values.

In my case, for a route defined as `/part/:id` it logs `/part/123`. I assume it will rewrite the output based on whatever routing strategy you use.

Answer (score 0):

Use can you use route guard. Allow navigation, display url, stop navigation further

```
import {CanActivate, Router, RouterStateSnapshot, ActivatedRouteSnapshot} from '@angular/router';

@Injectable()
export class AuthGuardService implements CanActivate {

  canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): boolean {
    alert(state.url);
    return false;
  }

}
```